# Save Information in Oracle Apex Webpages

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created an order information form or application . It is page 1= 'enter order number' which gives out information about the order . These are all classic reports or insert into page item  statements .

I want to be able to save these pages and comeback to them at a later date and add information or delete it . I do not want to have to go and re enter all the information again .

Is there anyway I can create a link for the partially completed form on a new page and come back to it again ?

Comment: I suggest you to go through this link: http://www.explorer.uk.com/adding-an-auto-save-feature-to-an-apex-page/

Comment: So, did you create a form (one page), or an application (many pages)? How are "classic **reports**" (regions, if not pages) related to "insert into page **item** statements"? (Statements? What statements?) You don't save "pages" but information, data. How? Submit the page (if it is a new row, push the CREATE button. If you modified something, APPLY CHANGES). Link to "partially completed form": I'd create an interactive report (with a form) which enables you to distinguish partially completed "forms" and navigate to a form in order to fill missing data.

Comment: I created two pages which have multiple regions with about 20 page items . Let's say 10 on each page . So this might probably be an application . Now I have a classic report which inserts the data into a text field . I then have many more SQL queries using that order number or the data I put in to the first box to run more queries . However not all the page items are completely filled so I am going to have to wait for other people to finish processing their data.

Comment: Once they finish I want to be able to access the partially completed form and finish completing the form with their data . I was thinking of creating an interactive report with links to take them to the form but I don't think I know how to .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this issue is by creating a table  . So for example if I had a page item account number - p6_acct . I would create a column in the table "Account_Number" . I would then create a PL/SQL procedure like insert into table (account_number) values (:p6_acct) this would successfully insert a record into  the table . At the final page I created a report in which I made one of the columns a link and set it so that every time the link in a particular row is clicked it links the columns back to the page items which in turn will lead to the form being filled again so in that way I have the information I want and I can correct it if I want too.